# Are there a scenario where in entity ref can insert more than one row in sql

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

In SQL, if we declare entity ref means, will there be any chances that it insert more than one row for entityref class during DB operations?

Comment: Is there any more context or detail you can provide? There's not enough info here to provide a reasoned answer.

Comment: Hi, i have posted a query in previous post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654305/loading-entities-in-linq. No answer i got. i have explained here.

Comment: Hi Rob, i have a doubt, can solve please, kindly reply

Comment: I don't see anything in your model that would cause EF to trigger multiple inserts for the same entity.

Comment: Hey my doubt is simple, i will explain you here. actually i have a entity ref class points to a table contains many entires but always it loads first row value, why so?. if we are doing entityref then always 0th row for a perticular foregin key will be picked?